# excel different SUM.IF array function

Tags: arrays, excel, sum

I have a very specific report, which I can't change the layout. Basicly, it looks like this:

```
   A     B       C
1  ASD   Other   10
2  ASD   Other   10
3  ASD   Other   10
4  JKL   Other   20
5  EFG   Other   5
6  EFG   Other   5
7  GHJ   Other   10
```

Ergo, lines CAN be repeated, and when they do, the value (C) stays the same for this line.

Using conditional formatting, (=$A2<>$A1), the repeated values (C-column only) are made white.

How can I do a SUM of these values, so that each distinct line will only be calculated once (Should return 45)?

In advance, thanks

PS: I'm using Excel 2003

Comment: When you say you "can't change the layout," does that mean you can't add a column? Or a row?  Where do you want the sum to show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I put this in cell `D9` and enter it as an array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter), it works for your scenario.  But note that there's blank row in Row 8 for this to work:

```
=SUM(IF(B1:B7<>B2:B8,D1:D7,0))
```

Comment: Damn i feel dumb right now; I've tried that exact formula a dozen times, but forgot the Ctrl+Shift+Enter...

Thank you for your swift reply

Comment: @GunnarKnudsen, I know that feeling! Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: You could avoid CSE if you want by using SUMPRODUCT, i.e. `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A7<>A2:A8)+0,C1:C7)`

Answer (score 0):

Does using the filter function work for you?

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-HP010073943.aspx

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/count-occurrences-of-values-or-unique-values-in-a-data-range-HP003056118.aspx

**EDIT:** I just solved it for you. Cheers!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsSiq9ugaybxdHk2MGIyVFRHbXN2LUYxdHRaTVM2cUE

Comment: No, sorry, The report needs to show all values, but only sum some of them... - However will give this a upvote...

Marc as given a answer which works fine for my needs...

Comment: I am a bit confused now since I got 45 as an answer too :) And it does show all values.

Comment: Oh you meant about the first two links. Yeah, don't mind them then. The working solution is on third :P