# Excel "Subtotal" array formula - Other form of sum.if

Tags: arrays, excel, function, sum

This is a continuation of the question [excel different SUM.IF array function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483048/excel-different-sum-if-array-function), But since I've marked that as solved, I created a new question.

What I wanted there was a distinct sum of some values, and I have implemented @Marc's solution. However the report requirements have changed. I now need to exclude all values that are hidden, but still keep the original calculation method. Basicly i want to add a feature in the same way a SUBTOTAL(109, ref) would work.

To this I've created a simple VBA function CellIsNotHidden(Range), which returns 0 or 1 depending on the cell.

Therefore my best guess would be a formula like: `{=SUM(IF($B1:$B7<>$B2:$B8,D2:D8,0)*CellIsNotHidden(D2:D8))}`

But this function doesn't work, because CellIsNotHidden is not an array function.

How can I solve this?

In advance, thanks

Gunnar

Edit:

Thought I should include the simple VBA function:

```
  Function CellIsNotHidden(InputRange As Range)

  If InputRange.Cells.Height = 0 Then
      CellIsNotHidden = 0
  Else
      If InputRange.Cells.Width = 0 Then
          CellIsNotHidden = 0
      Else
          CellIsNotHidden = 1
      End If
  End If

  End Function
```

Comment: Make you VBA function return a Range of 0 or 1 for each height invisible or visible

Comment: @Boud: I'm sorry, but I don't understand, by changing the top line to "Function CellIsNotHidden(InputRange As Range) As Range" nothing works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for UDF `CellIsNotHidden`. This will handle 1d (vector) and 2d arrays. Tested:

```
Function CellIsNotHidden(MyRange As Range) As Variant
  Dim RootCell As Range
  Dim tmpResult() As Long
  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long

On Error GoTo Whoops
  ReDim tmpResult(0 To MyRange.Rows.Count - 1, 0 To MyRange.Columns.Count - 1)
  Set RootCell = MyRange.Cells(1, 1)
  For j = 0 To MyRange.Columns.Count - 1
    For i = 0 To MyRange.Rows.Count - 1
      tmpResult(i, j) = Not (RootCell.Offset(i, j).EntireColumn.hidden Or RootCell.Offset(i, j).EntireRow.hidden)
    Next i
  Next j
  CellIsNotHidden = tmpResult
On Error GoTo 0
  Exit Function
Whoops:
  Debug.Print Err & " " & Error
End Function
```

Comment: BTW thanks for asking this question. This is a piece of code I have wanted in my library for a while, but did not get around to writing until you made the use case clear. Voting up!

Comment: Hi, that piece of code is just what I needed, works like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the UDF `CellIsNotHidden(D2:D8)` you could also try either of these:

```
SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(D2,ROW(D2:D8)-ROW(D2),))
SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(D2:D8,ROW(D2:D8)-MIN(ROW(D2:D8)),,1))
```